# Finding the geodesics between two points on a sphere

Tags: geometry, spherical-coordinates, geodesic, spherical-geometry

I am considering the following points on a sphere with $\rho=1$, $A=(0,1,0)$, $B=(-1,0,0)$ e $C=\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}, -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$. I need to find the geodesics $\gamma_{AB}$, $\gamma_{BC}$ e $\gamma_{AC}$. My professor used a material with general theorems and prepositions and with no examples. I am looking for a way to start maybe with $\gamma_{AB}$.

I thought first to write $A$ and $B$ in polar coordinates, but still I can find no formula to apply these points on and find this geodesic.

ANY tips would be highly appreciated.

Comment: HINT. $$\cos\angle AOC=(A-O)\cdot(C-O).$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\vec{a} = (0, 1, 0)$, and $\vec{b} = (-1, 0, 0)$.

These two points and origin (center of the sphere) are on a plane that passes through origin, and whose normal is
$$\vec{n} = \vec{a} \times \vec{b} = (0, 0, 1)$$
because vector cross product yields a vector that is perpendicular to both $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$, i.e. $\vec{n} \perp \vec{a}$ and $\vec{n} \perp \vec{b}$, by definition.

This plane contains both geodesics (minimum and maximum distance between the two points) between $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$, because the intersection with the sphere is the great circle.

Furthermore,
$$\cos\theta = \frac{\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}}{\left\lVert\vec{a}\right\rVert \left\lVert\vec{b}\right\rVert}$$
where $\theta$ is the angular separation between $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$.

If you rotate $\vec{a}$ around vector $\vec{n}$ by angle $\theta$, you'll arrive at $\vec{b}$.  (Here, $\lVert\vec{a}\rVert = \lVert\vec{b}\rVert = 1$; more generally, you'll rotate $\vec{a}$ *parallel to* $\vec{b}$ using this scheme.)

Comment: I just can't see the equation of the geodesics $\gamma_{AB}$

Comment: Which [form of geodesic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic) would you like?  If you use $R(\vec{v}, \hat{k}, \theta)$ for [Rodrigues' rotation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula), and $\hat{n} = \vec{n} / \lVert \vec{n} \rVert$, then the geodesic between $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ is the locus of points $R(\vec{a}, \hat{n}, \varphi)$ with $0 \le \varphi \le \theta$.

Comment: Or, if you use $\hat{a}=\vec{a}/\lVert\vec{a}\rVert$, and apply one step of [Gram–Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) to orthogonalize $\vec{b}$ with respect to $\hat{a}$, i.e. $\vec{c} = \hat{a} - (\hat{a} \cdot \vec{b}) \hat{a}$, $\hat{c} = \vec{c}/\lVert\vec{c}\rVert$, then the geodesic between $\hat{a}$ and $\vec{b}/\lVert\vec{b}\rVert$ is $\vec{p} = \hat{a}\cos\varphi + \hat{c}\sin\varphi$, $0 \le \varphi \le \theta$.

Comment: These apply to any points $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ that are not collinear with origin (i.e., $\vec{b} \ne \lambda \vec{a}, \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$).  If they are, they are either effectively opposite poles with an infinite number of geodesics between them, or correspond to the same point on the unit sphere.